# How to push the docker image to DTR using Jenkins multibranch pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My problem statement is to push the docker image to DTR using Jenkins multibranch pipeline.
I want to configure my Jenkins file in such a way that it will build the image and then Push it.

for building the image I will use 10.1.2.3 machine and DTR will be https://something.dtr01.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com/

I am totally new to Jenkins as per the instruction I have put the sample Jenkins file in the git repo.

Please suggest me the configuration changes in Jenkisfile

```
node {
    // Clean workspace before doing anything
    deleteDir()

    try {
        stage ('Clone') {
            checkout scm
        }
        stage ('Build') {
            "echo 'shell scripts to build project...'"
        }
        stage ('Tests') {
            parallel 'static': {
                sh "echo 'shell scripts to run static tests...'"
            },
            'unit': {
                sh "echo 'shell scripts to run unit tests...'"
            },
            'integration': {
                sh "echo 'shell scripts to run integration tests...'"
            }
        }
        stage ('Deploy') {
            sh "echo 'shell scripts to deploy to server...'"
        }
    } catch (err) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
        throw err
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciable